# What is the term for a show or movie that has no actual story?

Tags: technique, plot, terminology

When i see so many generic trash shows like "The Mist" i cant help to wonder, what is the story exactly? Why do they show so much unnecessary info, like history and stories from minor characters that no one cares for, alot of shows nowadays do this, where is the plot? There must be a term for something like this, in "The Mist" situation, its of course about how theres a mist falling over the town. People are trying to survive it i get that, but whats the story? Its like with the walking dead, yeah people are surviving, but whats the actual story and plot? If someone can go into detail upon what im talking about itd be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: *The Mist* in particular is adapted from a short story by Stephen King, which was much more tightly plotted. If the show feels like it's stuffed with filler, that's because it probably is.

Comment: Your question title and your actual question do not match. Your title is a request for an individual term, which is off topic here. But your question has more to do with the literary merit of elements other than plot. Can you edit you title to better reflect the precise question you are asking?

Comment: I suspect this is accumulating close votes because [questions seeking to interpret or analyze an existing work (except when applied to a real-world writing project) are off-topic here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/244/26). Does this apply to a writing project of yours? If so, please consider including that in the question.

Answer (score 5):

They are character driven rather than plot driven. It is the story of the characters they are selling, the plot is simply the situation they are in and a way to show the who the characters are. The advantage of shows with large casts is that if one leaves the show doesn't fall apart, like Seinfeld would have had Jerry Seinfeld left or the original Beauty and the Beast when Linda Hamilton left it lasted one more season. So a large cast, and your supposed to be interested in the characters and there actions more than the story they are living.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes "slice-of-life" pics are considered plotless, or without a story. There are others too, and I know The Mist is anything but slice-of-life, but to say it is without a story doesn't do justice to ones that really have no plot or consequences or anything really at stake.